# sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (subscriptions) - default value of column [status] is not constant

Tags: sql, sqlite

Пытаюсь взять значение столбца STATUS, выдаёт ошибку: "sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (subscriptions) - default value of column [status] is not constant"

```
def update_subscription(self):
    """Обновляем статус подписки пользователя"""
    with self.connection:


        status_ind = 'status'

        query = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ' + status_ind), (status_ind, ).fetchall()
```

Comment: У Вас в структуре таблицы проблема, а не в отдельном запросе. Исправляйте.

Comment: @Akina как это можно исправить или проверить, я увы не знаю